# Warning: Detected changes to resource xxx which is currently being deleted

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s

This is a k3s cluster on multipass virtual machines.

I created a persisten volume and now I can not delete it. It got deleted but when I recreate it I got an Error:

```
kubectl delete -f persistentVolume.yaml

persistentvolume "postgres-pv" deleted
```

but if I want to create the same volume

```
kubectl apply -f persistentVolume.yaml 

Warning: Detected changes to resource postgres-pv which is currently being deleted.

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    app: postgres
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /pendrive/datakuber
```

And the path is empty.

Thank

Comment: Seems to be your issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer in the answer section for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Yes I added "SOLVED" and the link I used to fix it

Comment: You have posted a solution in the question itself. Post the solution in the below answer section(YOUR Answer) and accept the answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: I did that sorry

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:** I followed [ Can't remove terminating persistent volumes (PV) [Can't remove terminating persistent volumes (PV)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77258#issuecomment-502209800)

```
kubectl patch pv postgres-pv -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

and I retry the kubectl delete and recreated the persisten volume without any error.